# Can't pass details from FlatList items to Modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

I have FlatList and I want to open each FlatList Item in Modal to see details. In this example I am trying to click on            {rowData.data.display_name} to see               {rowData.data.display_name} inside of Modal. I get data from API and when I open Modal it's not the same item that I clicked on. I am not sure how would I set up item id to see the same item inside of Modal? Any help would be appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state._data}
          renderItem={({item: rowData}) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>

                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.openModal}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    {rowData.data.display_name}
                  </Text>   
                </TouchableOpacity>

            <Modal
          style={styles.modal}
         ref={(modal) => this.modal = modal}
                coverScreen={true}
          swipeToClose={this.state.swipeToClose}
          onClosed={this.onClose}
          onOpened={this.onOpen}
          onClosingState={this.onClosingState}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>                     
          {rowData.data.display_name}
       </Text>
        </Modal>
           </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should put the Modal outside the FlatList. The way you codded it you're overwritting the "this.modal" every time a new Item from the list is created.

Then you would just accept changing the text of the Modal (probably via state) on your openModal function inside the Modal component, and on your renderItem, change the onPress to pass the infos from the container you want the modal to show.

```
            onPress={()=> this.openModal(rowData.data)}>
```